# Error=MissingRegistration when using FCM in PHP

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the following code in php to send push notification to my android device

```
        $fields['to'] = $to;
        $fields['notification'] = $data;

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key='FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY',
            'Content-Type:application/json'
        );

        $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo($result);
```

But I keep getting MissingRegistrationError
I also tried json_encode($fields), but then I get the error

```
{
  "multicast_id": 19351993433794134,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `json_encode()`ing was the right move - the "InvalidRegistration" is a hint that `$to` either doesn't contain a *valid* registration token, or a valid registration token that is not registered to the project identified by your server key.

Comment: When I am using the curl command using same server key and the token in the terminal  then I get the notification in my device

Answer (score 0):

Change curl version to 1.1 by adding the following line

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```